# Find all $n,x \in \Bbb N$ such that $3\cdot2^x+4=n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

> Find all $n,x \in \Bbb N$ such that $3\cdot2^x+4=n^2$

Arranging the equation a bit one has that $$(n-2)(n+2)=3\cdot2^x.$$

Now considering the cases $n-2=3, n+2=2^x$ from $n-2=3 \Rightarrow n=5$. Substituting this to $n+2=2^x \Rightarrow 7=2^x$ which isn't an integer solution.

Considering the opposite $n+2=3$ and $n-2=2^x$ one gets that $n+2=3 \Rightarrow n=1$ and substituting this to $n-2=2^x$ we have that $-1=2^x$ which also doesn't have any solutions.

What am I missing here since this seemed to have $3$ pairs of solutions?

Comment: What if $n+2=6$ and $n-2=  2^{x-1}$, for example?

Comment: $n-2 = 3(2^{x-k}); n+2 = 3(2^{x-k})$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How did you come up with these equations? You're assuming that $x>1$?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1830106p12251997)

Comment: My point was merely that just because $(n-2)(n+2)=3\cdot 2^x$ does not necessarily mean $\{n-2,n+2\}=\{3,2^x\}$, as you seemed to assume

Comment: @J.W.Tanner This is due to the fact that $2$ has a variable as a power?

Comment: I'm just saying I think you're missing that $3\cdot2^x$ could be expressed as a product of numbers other than $3$ and $2^x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good start; writing
$$(n-2)(n+2)=3\cdot2^x,$$
shows, by unique factorization of integers, that
$$n-2=2^a3^b,\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n+2=2^c3^d,$$
for nonnegative integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ with $a+c=x$ and $b+d=1$. Of course $b+d=1$ leaves very few options for $b$ and $d$. Can you continue from here?

**Solution:**

> It follows that $$2^{x-a}3^{1-b}-2^a3^b=(n+2)-(n-2)=4,$$ so if $x\geq3$ we see that either $a\geq2$ or $x-a\geq2$. Then reducing mod $4$ shows that in fact  $a\geq2$ *and* $x-a\geq2$, and so $$2^{x-a-2}3^{1-b}-2^{a-2}3^b=(n+2)-(n-2)=1.$$  Then precisely one of the two factors on the left hand side is odd, meaning that either $x-a-2=0$ or $a-2=0$, and so correspondingly either $$3^{1-b}-2^{a-2}3^b=1\qquad\text{ or }\qquad2^{x-4}3^{1-b}-3^b=1.$$ For the former, note that $3^{1-b}\in\{1,3\}$. Clearly $3^{1-b}=1$ does not yield a solution, so $3^{1-b}=3$ and hence $b=0$. Then $2^{a-2}=2$ and so $a=3$, yielding the solution $x=5$ with $n=10$. 
>  
> For the latter, note again that $3^b\in\{1,3\}$. A quick check shows that $3^b=1$ does not yield a solution, so $3^b=3$ and hence $b=1$. Then $2^{x-4}=4$, yielding the solution $x=6$ with $n=14$. 
>  
>  Finally we are left with the case $x\leq3$. Another quick check yields the last solution $x=2$ with $n=4$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! What confuses me is the part "unique factorization of integers". I see that obviously $3$ and $2$ are primes, but I'm not sure I entirely understand what's happening here.

Comment: Every positive integer $n$ can be expressed as a product of prime numbers in *precisely one way*. This is the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), I recommend reading up on the details at the linked Wikipedia page. So
$$n-2=\prod_p p^{a_p}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n+2=\prod_p p^{b_p},$$
for *uniquely determined* nonnegative integers $a_p$ and $b_p$, where $p$ ranges over all prime numbers. Of course $a_p=0$ and $b_p=0$ for all but finitely many prime numbers...[Continued]

Comment: [Continued]...Now the identity you found shows that
$$2^x\cdot3=(n-2)(n+2)=\prod_pa^p\prod_pp^{b_p}=\prod_pp^{a_p+b_p}.$$
and so by the uniqueness of prime factorization, it must be the case that $a_2+b_2=x$ and $a_3+b_3=1$ and $a_p+b_p=0$ for all $p>3$.

Comment: This is a standard method used in solving *many* (if not most) diophantine equations, often without mention, so it is worth understanding.